# How could I use fish( or zsh) rather than default bash in a anaconda enviroment

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, zsh, fish

I installed anaconda and fish, and i run the following commands

```
> echo /usr/local/bin/fish | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
> chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish
```

then i restart the terminal, it says

```
(base) username@pop-os:~$
```

i realize it's the base environment of conda, then after search, I run another command

```
conda init fish
```

then restart the terminal, it's still a bash rather than fish.

is there any way i can benefits both from conda and fish at the same time?

Comment: Depending on what exactly "restart the terminal" means here, you are getting your login shell, not a shell started by `conda`.

Comment: @chepner but one doesn't need "*a shell started by conda*". The `conda init` command adds Conda's shell initialization code to the appropriate resources file (e.g., `.zshrc`), making all future launches of that shell Conda-aware. Sounds more like the user is not successful in changing their default shell to `fish`.

Comment: conda won't change your shell. As @merv says, sounds like your default shell hasn't changed. Try restarting your terminal emulator (Terminal.app, Windows Terminal, etc)

Comment: Thanks for all of you  I realize I just need to reboot the system to make the change of default terminal set. What a stupid .

Answer (score 0):

All I need to do is reboot my system so the change of default terminal will be set.

Also, I misunderstand the conda people could refer to the comments to say details.

Comment: I can't believe that in Linux, a **reboot** is necessary to make such a change work. Now it works for you, but if the topic itself is of interest to you (and I think it is interesting and worth finding out the details), may I suggest that you repost your question at [su], adding that the only solution you found was rebooting the system. I have unfortunately not enough administration experience to suggest something better.